# How to enable seperate connection for consumer in RabbitMQ (Spring Boot)?

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I am using spring boot and is looking for some options to enable separate connection for listener via property file configurations as it is told as the best practice.

I have seen this,
[separate-connection](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp//reference/html/_reference.html#separate-connection)

Is there any example or snippet if needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not currently available as a property (I suggest you request a new feature as a Boot GitHub issue).

However, you can easily configure it with a custom bean definition, such as:

```
@Bean
public Object templateConfigurer(RabbitTemplate template) {
    template.setUsePublisherConnection(true);
    return new Object();
}
```